# Why top and bottom padding not visible without float

Tags: html, css

Why top and bottom padding visible only if I add float?

Here are the 2 snippets for your reference.

When float is added:

```css
nav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">College Reviews</a>
</nav>
```

When float is removed:

```css
nav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <a href="#">Hello</a>
        <a href="#">World</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because tag `a` has an inline display attribute by default.

```css
nav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">College Reviews</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yeah i got it partially. Actually I have not learnt display property yet.

Comment: @AryavBhola you can check there i think it's good docs [https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)